# How to change a GCP Load balancer's certificate with no downtime?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcp-load-balancer

I'm trying to experiment with changing the domain name & certificate associated with a GCP Load Balancer.

Currently, the domain name and certificate is attached to Load Balancer A, and I want to attach that domain to Load Balancer B with no downtime to the site.

The two load balancers are of different types, so I cannot change the associated Backend to a Service B.

I'm trying to change the certificate associated with Load Balancer B to the preferred domain, then update the DNS records to point to that Load Balancer.

However, this results in a 404, "your connection is unsecure".

The certificate is shown in ACTIVE state within GCP. As it has previously been activated when attached to Load Balancer A.

Is there anyway to avoid the site being unavailable, without the unsecure certificate warning?

Comment: Is your workload running as MIG? Running on GKE?  Something else...?  If you're running it on GKE, are you using Ingress?

Comment: It's not running on GKE, no ingress is configured or needed. It's working fine, before trying to switch domain and certificate.

Answer (score 0):

A short answer would be NO.

Moving the domain from Load Balancer A to B would require updating the current `A Record` of your DNS from the front end IP of Load Balancer A to the front end IP of Load Balancer B. In general, DNS changes are processed and propagated within [`48 hours`](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7514107?hl=en#:%7E:text=Changes%20with%20your%20domain%20host), but sometimes it can take up to `72 hours`.

Secondly, the certificate requires to have the correct front end IP for successful provisioning. Since the current certificate points to the front end IP of Load Balancer A, you'll need to reprovision another SSL certificate for Load Balancer B which will be associated to its own Front End IP.

Provisioning a Google-managed certificate might take up to [`60 minutes`](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates/troubleshooting#:%7E:text=Provisioning%20a%20Google%2Dmanaged%20certificate,the%20changes%20to%20fully%20propagate.) from the moment your DNS and load balancer configuration changes have propagated across the internet. If you have updated your DNS configuration recently, it can take a significant amount of time for the changes to fully propagate.

The best approach will be to plan these changes ahead of time.